# ORDER BY two variable parts of a string

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed further. How do I order my results accordingly?

```
10 x  2 ml
10 x 10 ml
 4 x 20 ml
```

`10 x 2 ml` should come first because `2 ml` is smaller than `10 ml`.
And then order by the number that comes before the multiplication sign.

Comment: Please, provide some data and desired result. For now it's not fully clear

Comment: @AlmaDo That's putting it mildly!

Comment: @AlmaDo Okay sorry for being unclear. I managed to solve this myself and will provide an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved my own question:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(size, INSTR(size, 'x') + 2) + 0, size + 0
```

Comment: I see. I guess SUBSTRING_INDEX(size,'x ',-1)+0 would also work

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but it's **really** ugly, especially if the tables are big and you need performance:

```
ORDER BY  TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(field_name,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field_name,'x',1),'x'),''),'ml',''))
```

it replaces SUBSTRING_INDEX('ABCx123ml','x',1); //ABC  and ml with blanks, triming it, leaving only the value needed for order...